# Existe alguma forma de fazer o apache case insensitive no linux?

Tags: php, apache, sensibilidade-de-caixa

Fiz toda a aplicação usando o Windows,e é relativamente grande, e em muitas partes do código esqueci das regras de case sensitive, como o windows ignora isso não pensei em mudar nada, só que estou usando uma hospedagem Linux, e a aplicação está dando diversos problemas. existe alguma forma de fazer o apache trabalhar case insensitive?

Minha configuração atual do `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 400 /404
ErrorDocument 401 /404
ErrorDocument 403 /404
ErrorDocument 500 /404
```

Comment: O mod_rewrite é case sensitive por padrão. Use a flag [NC] para torná-o case insensitive. Não vou responder pois não está claro a quê se refere na pergunta. É sobre mod_rewrite ou sobre sistema de arquivos?

Comment: O sistema de arquivos, o apache no linux sendo específico, é possível? ou o que puder ser case insensitive...

Comment: Terá que normalizar os nomes dos seus arquivos. Adote boas práticas de programação para evitar esse tipo de transtorno. De outro modo, sim é possível forçar o Linux como case insensitve para o filesystem, mas é algo que exige acesso administrativo e pode não ser algo bom.